# Can we move quantifiers $\forall,\exists$ to the front if there aren't variable collisions?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let's say I have a formula $\phi$ in First Order Logic, which contains some existential and universal quantifiers quantifiers $\exists, \forall$.

Supposed that in $\phi$ there are no collisions in variables names.

Can we take all the quantifiers of $\phi$, move it on the left (in the same order that appears in $\phi$)?

Example:
$$\phi_1 = \forall x P(x )\rightarrow \exists y T(y) \\
\phi_2 = \forall x\exists y P(x )\rightarrow  T(y) \\
\phi_1 \overset{?}{\equiv} \phi_2$$

Obviously, I'm interested in the general case, not in this one, which is shown just to express the question using an example

I looked this up on Google, and I found many material which talks about prenex normal form, which solves this problem using skolemization, however I can't find an answer to this direct question, and skolemization makes it valid for every instance of $\phi$ that I try it on (but obviously trying many times is not a valid proof )

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [prenex normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) tells you exactly7 what you need to do and doesn't mention skolemization (which isn't required unless you you want to get rid of any quantifier alternation).

Comment: @RobArthan: I suspect that the source of the confusion is that, in order to skolemize a formula, it must be in prenex normal form; furthermore, this pair of transformations is commonly applied in conversion to conjunctive normal form, which is IMHO the most interesting normal form of the three (because of resolution). It would be easy to conflate them if you always do them one after the other in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Example:
> $$\phi_1 := \forall x\; P(x )\rightarrow \exists y\; T(y) \\
> \phi_2 := \color{green}{\Big(}\forall x\;\exists y\; P(x) \color{green}{\Big)}\rightarrow  T(y) \\$$

$$\phi_3 := \forall x\;\exists y \Big( P(x )\rightarrow  T(y) \Big)\\
\phi_4 := \exists x\;\exists y\;\Big( P(x )\rightarrow  T(y)\Big)$$

Formulae $1$ and $4$ are equivalent, whereas neither formula $2$ nor $3$ are equivalent to any of the others.

Therefore, non-collision is not a sufficient condition for a formula to be equivalent to the new one created by simply shifting its quantifiers to the front.

---

**Addendum**

> can you provide a counterexample where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_3$ are not equals? or an explanation

Consider the set of integers. Let
 $P(x) := x$ is even, and
 $T(x) := x$ is smaller than itself.

For $x=2,$ no integer can make $\Big( P(x )\rightarrow  T(y) \Big)$ true; thus, $\phi_3$ is false.

On the other hand, $\phi_1$ is vacuously true.

Comment: sorry but $\phi_2$ has y as free variable, so it's not just moving quantifiers on the left, but as far as I understood, 1 and 3 are not equivalent (which is what I'm asking)

Comment: 1. I was implicitly pointing out that your $\phi_2$ contains a free variable, and explicitly pointing out that $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ don't mean the same.  2. "*but as far as I understood, 1 and 3 are not equivalent*" That's what I said.

Comment: then, can you provide a counterexample where those 2 formulas are not equals? or an explanation for why it's not the case

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your general question is very much "no", because moving a quantifier past a connective can change the quantifier. For instance, $\neg \forall x \phi(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x \neg\phi(x)$ and in the vast majority of cases is not equivalent to $\forall x \neg \phi(x)$.

Comment: So the answer is actually "yes",  but the sense of the quantifiers has to change as you lift the quantifiers up through the propositional connectives.

Answer (score 2):

In this very particular case, NO, $\phi_1$ is NOT equivalent to $\phi_2$, but the overall "intuition" is correct, except for one edge case that was overlooked.

Let me elaborate. It is indeed the case (assuming no name collisions, obviously) that:

$\forall x Px \land \forall y Qy \iff \forall x \forall y(Px \land Qy) $

$\forall x Px \land \exists y Qy \iff \forall x \exists y(Px \land Qy) $

$\exists x Px \land \forall y Qy \iff \exists x \forall y(Px \land Qy) $

$\exists x Px \land \exists y Qy \iff \exists x \exists y(Px \land Qy) $

$\forall x Px \lor \forall y Qy \iff \forall x \forall y(Px \lor Qy) $

$\forall x Px \lor \exists y Qy \iff \forall x \exists y(Px \lor Qy) $

$\exists x Px \lor \forall y Qy \iff \exists x \forall y(Px \lor Qy) $

$\exists x Px \lor \exists y Qy \iff \exists x \exists y(Px \lor Qy) $

This rule does NOT hold true when we are talking about the first predicate of an implication ($a\implies b$), rather than disjunction ($a \lor b$) or conjuction ($a \land b$). E.g. in your case, $\forall x Px \implies \exists y Qy$ is NOT equivalent to $\forall x Px \implies \exists y Qy$. Rather, by rewriting the implication as a disjunction, we can show that:

$\forall x Px \implies \exists y Qy$

$\iff \neg \forall x Px \lor \exists y Qy$

$\iff \exists x \neg Px \lor \exists y Qy$

$\iff \exists x \exists y (\neg Px \lor Qy)$

$\iff \exists x \exists y (Px \implies Qy)$

Ultimately, we were able to show that:

$\forall x Px \implies \exists y Qy \iff \exists x \exists y (Px \implies Qy)$

In a similiar fashion, we can show all the other cases as well:

$\exists x Px \implies \exists y Qy \iff \forall x \exists y (Px \implies Qy)$

$\forall x Px \implies \forall y Qy \iff \exists x \forall y (Px \implies Qy)$

$\exists x Px \implies \forall y Qy \iff \forall x \forall y (Px \implies Qy)$

So yes, your initial intuition does hold true, as long as there are no implications involved. If there is an implication ivolved, then you will have to "switch" the quantifier of the first predicate when moving the quantifiers around, while the quantifier of the second predicate remains the same, just like with disjunction and conjuction.

After reading your question, I am not too sure if you were only interested in knowing the rules for "moving" quantifiers, or if you wanted a (semi)formal proof for it as well. If you are also interested in having a proof, let me know in the comments and I will edit my question later. In either case, I hope I was able to help!

Comment: therefore we need first to convert to CNF, and then from there we can move them in front "in a blind way"?

Comment: The algorithm for putting a formula into prenex normal form is well-known. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form. It does not require conversion to CNF as a preliminary, which is good because the CNF could be much longer than the original.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia essentially yes, just don't forget to switch the first quantifier when dealing with an implication. However, it is also important to keep in mind that this rule will not always be useful when dealing with predicates. E.g. for the statement $\forall x Px \land \forall x \neg Px$, we can tell intuitively that it is false, but changing the variable name of the second statement ($\forall x Px \land \forall y \neg Py$) and "merging" them together 
($\forall x \forall y(Px \land \neg Py)$) won't help us show that it is false. Actually, it is often more helpful to do the opposite.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia in retrospective, if we know that $\forall x \forall y(Px \land Py)$, this implies (by considering only those $y$ for which $y=x$) that $\forall x(Px \land \neg Px)$, which is false. On second thought, maybe moving the quantifiers around CAN always help solve a problem, though it is not always the most intuitive method of doing so.